What is the difference between aes encryption in python and javascript
When I use JavaScript to encrypt some string:
import crypto from 'crypto';

function encryptSeed(text, key, iv) {
    key = Buffer.from(key, "utf8"),
    console.log("key:" + key.toString("hex"));
    iv = Buffer.from(iv, "utf8");
    console.log("iv:" + iv.toString("hex"));
    text = Buffer.from(text, "hex");
    console.log("text:" + text.toString("hex"));
    var c = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-128-cbc", key, iv);
    var d = c.update(text)
    d = Buffer.concat([d, c.final()]);
    console.log("result:" + d.toString("hex"));
    return d.toString("utf8");
}

And when I use python to encrypt the same string:
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def encrypt_seed(text, key, iv):
    key_bytes = key.encode("utf8")
    print("key:" + key_bytes.hex())
    iv_bytes = iv.encode("utf8")
    print("iv:" + iv_bytes.hex())
    cryptor = AES.new(key_bytes, AES.MODE_CBC, iv_bytes)
    text_bytes = bytes.fromhex(text)
    print("text:" + text_bytes.hex())
    ciphertext = cryptor.encrypt(text_bytes)
    print("result:" + ciphertext.hex())
    return ciphertext.decode('utf-8')

The AES result is different, how can I solve it?

Why do you use crypto,createDecipheriv(..) if you want to encrypt ?

I am so sorry, I have made a stupid mistake

@Singun Please remember to accept my answer if it helped you.


You're using createDecipheriv; you'll want createCipheriv.
By default, Node crypto does automagical PKCS padding; you'll want to disable that since your input is exactly 16 bytes long.

import crypto from "crypto";

function encryptSeed(text, key, iv) {
  key = Buffer.from(key, "utf8");
  console.log("JS key:", key.toString("hex"));
  iv = Buffer.from(iv, "utf8");
  console.log("JS iv:", iv.toString("hex"));
  text = Buffer.from(text, "hex");
  console.log("JS text:", text.toString("hex"));
  var c = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-128-cbc", key, iv);
  c.setAutoPadding(false);
  var result = Buffer.concat([c.update(text), c.final()]);
  console.log("JS result:", result.toString("hex"));
}

encryptSeed("164edb20a24d2244047dab3e4e779426", "bdb187ce475a2531", "97f00becc884661d");

and
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


def encrypt_seed(text, key, iv):
    key_bytes = key.encode("utf8")
    print("Py key:", key_bytes.hex())
    iv_bytes = iv.encode("utf8")
    print("Py iv:", iv_bytes.hex())
    cryptor = AES.new(key_bytes, AES.MODE_CBC, iv_bytes)
    text_bytes = bytes.fromhex(text)
    print("Py text:", text_bytes.hex())
    ciphertext = cryptor.encrypt(text_bytes)
    print("Py result:", ciphertext.hex())


encrypt_seed("164edb20a24d2244047dab3e4e779426", "bdb187ce475a2531", "97f00becc884661d")

print the equivalent result.
